# Mandrill API: Filter out scheduled emails list by metadata

Tags: python, mandrill

My application manages bookings that are planned for a certain date, and I have to send several reminder emails 1, 2 and 3 days before the booking date.

Using Mandrill's [scheduling](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/24331201-Can-I-schedule-a-message-to-send-at-a-specific-time-) feature, I'm able to schedule the sending at the appropriate moment. I add a `booking_id` metadata to each email.

Now in my app, I'd like to **show a list of all scheduled emails associated with a particular booking**. So far I've tried the following:

1) [Retrieving the list of all scheduled emails](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.python.html#method=list-scheduled) and among them, filtering out those with the correct `booking_id`: **not feasible** as the JSON returned by `messages.list-scheduled` does not hold any metadata.

2) Retrieving the list of all scheduled emails, fetching each email's `booking_id` via `messages.info` and filtering out: **not feasible**: `messages.info` doesn't accept the `id` of a scheduled email.

3) [Searching by metadata](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.python.html#method=search) and filtering out scheduled emails: **not feasible** as `messages.search` only returns sent emails.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet would probably be to store the data when you schedule the email in the first place, in your own database, including the recipient, subject line, and what data you want to be able to display. If you need or want to be able to compare that to the messages scheduled in Mandrill, store the `_id` that's returned for each scheduled message, too, in your database, so you have a unique identifier to compare against. If you want to periodically confirm that the info Mandrill has matches up with your expectations, then on some interval, grab the list of scheduled messages (once per day, for example).